# Unable to assign image to the picture box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Getting below error while assigning the image to the picture box in vb.net.

**Resource with identifier 'bmpPAYMENTCURR' not found**.

below is the code for reference.

```
  frmMain.imgPaymentType.Image = VB6.LoadResPicture("PAYMENTCURR", VB6.LoadResConstants.ResBitmap)
```

Comment: are you using vb6 or vb.net?

Comment: I am using VB.Net..But I have to use vb6 dll to use the VB6.LoadResPicture function

Comment: Same thing is working fine in VB6 but in VB.Net it is not working..

Comment: Are you just wanting to display an image within the picturebox?

Comment: Yes, but want to display image using VB6.LoadResPicture

Comment: im sorry, i have never used vb6 before, i mainly use c#, can you explain more, is it just a standard picture? or is there something special about it?